# Execute function on both onkeyenter as blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some problems with executing a function depending on whether the 'blur' or 'keydown' event is triggered.

I am having the following situation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function blurChange(e) {
        clearTimeout(blurChange.timeout);
        blurChange.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            var entered_date = $('.format').val().split('-');
            if (entered_date[2].length == '4' && (entered_date[1].length == '2' || entered_date[1].length == '1') && (entered_date[0].length == '2' || entered_date[0].length == '1')) {
                console.log("yes");
                $('.formatted-date').off('blur change');
            } else {
                $('.error').html("error");
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    $('.format').on('blur keydown', blurChange);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="format" value="01-02-2099">
<span class="error"></span>
```

The situation that I am seeking for is to have an input field where a user can fill any date in the given format and when the input lost his focus the `console.log` is triggered. I also want that this console.log is triggered when pressing the '**enter**' button (event code 13).

In short,
I want to have two situations working:

- Situation 1: The input is checked with the if statement if the user is blurring (unfocus)
- Situation 2: The input is checked with the if statement if the user press enter within the input field.

So in both situations(blur, onkeyenter) the input should be checked. I hope that I made myself clear. For any questions please ask.

DEMO HERE: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pdj94r16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not changing your code too much, you could simply do:

`if((e.type == "keydown" && keycode == 13) 
   || e.type == "blur")`

Before your current if statement.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecoosotv/1/)

Although it may make more sense to separate them like here:

[Possible better way](https://jsfiddle.net/ecoosotv/3/)

I've also added this `$('.error').html("");` so the error message clears when data is correct.

Comment: awesome! After a lot of debugging I never thought of this solution. Thank you! I would go with your: "possible better way"

Comment: glad it helped! :)